# How to find out which activity started the intent that triggered your BroadCastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app, where some calls can be made when you press a button. 
I call a number with:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+o.getTel()));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I have a broadcast receiver that detects end of call.
 But this broadcast receiver also receives calls started from other apps (e.g. dialer app).

How can i differentiate calls started from other apps from calls started in mine?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call sendBroadcast(intent), add an extra to the intent,

e.g **i.putExtra("sender", "my identifier")**

Then in the onReceive of the receiver

**String encodedType = intent.getStringExtra("sender");**

Then you can test for this string.

Comment: I don't see why you can't pass the extra in on the intent when you start your number caller/dialler activity, then send it back in the sendBroadcast when it finishes. Other apps won't have added the extra you specify.